# TMUX pane border colors are being overridden

Tags: tmux

I'm using tmux and a theme (dreamsofcode-io/catppucin-tmux) and I can't get my pane border color settings to stick because apparently it's being overridden by the theme.

When I source `.tmux.conf` the colors I want flash on briefly as per my settings, then revert. I thought putting the border settings after the theme would keep them, but it doesn't help.

How do I get my settings to override the theme for just the borders?

Here's the relevant part of my tmux config (skipping key bindings and the like):

```
# List of plugins
set -g @plugin 'tmux-plugins/tpm'
set -g @plugin 'tmux-plugins/tmux-sensible'
set -g @plugin 'tmux-plugins/tmux-resurrect'
set -g @plugin 'dreamsofcode-io/catppuccin-tmux'
set -g @plugin 'tmux-plugins/tmux-yank'

# set border styles
set -g pane-active-border-style "fg=colour244"
set -g pane-border-style "fg=magenta"

set-environment -g PATH "/usr/local/bin:/bin:/usr/bin"
# Initialize TMUX plugin manager (keep this line at the very bottom of tmux.conf)
run -b '~/.tmux/plugins/tpm/tpm'
#set -g terminal-overrides '*88col*:colors=88,*256col*:colors=256,xterm*:XT:Ms=\E]52;%p1%s;%p2%s\007:Cs=\E]12;%p1%s\007:Cr=\E]112\007:Ss=\E]50;CursorShape=%?%p1%{3}%<%t%{0}%e%p1%{2}%-%;%d\007'
```

After briefly (0.5s) flashing the right colors, it returns to this; the active border is ok, but the inactive border is almost invisible.

[image: screenshot of border styles]

Answer (score 2):

I was having the exact same problem and I tried removing the `-g` in the set commands and it worked. My file looks very similar to yours and when I use:

```
set pane-active-border-style fg=red
set pane-border-style fg=blue
```

I've spent ages searching trying to work out why it wasn't working and I happened to notice in the tmux file for catppuccin that it uses "set" rather than "set -g" so I thought I'd give it a try, and thankfully it worked.

Also, the blue and red I've used above appear to be the blue and red shades from the theme rather than raw red and blue.

HTH,
Alex

Answer (score 0):

Turns out it was conflicts from the theme in vimrc and my Neovim config.